# Edge browser populating multiple textboxes

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, microsoft-edge

I'm having some problems with textboxes in Edge browser. When I click on a textbox (regular <input type="text"), it shows some options I entered before. That's fine but when I select one, other textboxes gets affected. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

You see in this image, in the modal div, I selected Notebook and the textbox at the background also changed. They have different name and id attributes and also I haven't even picked anything yet on the modal, just hovering on the items in the dropdown already affects the textbox at the background.

What could be causing this? I've already checked several times that they have different attributes. Here is their markup:

**This is for the modal:**

```
<div styleName="field-container">
    <label className={classes.label} htmlFor="termName">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" styleName="field-container__input-text field-container__input-text--long" name="termName" id="termName" required autoFocus autoComplete="off" />
</div>
```

**This is for the background:**

```
<div styleName="field-container">
    <label className={classes.label} htmlFor="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" styleName="field-container__input-text field-container__input-text--long" name="name" id="name" required autoFocus autoComplete="off" />
</div>
```

This Edge dropdown show "Manage Personal Info..." at the bottom by the way.

Comment: Which version of Edge are you using? Does the issue only occur in Edge? It seems to be hard to find the cause from the above code. It could be better if you can provide the code snippet which can **run and reproduce** the issue. So that we can have a test and see how to help.